# Firebase delete query result

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the following code that I'm trying to remove quiz records with:

```
  var authref = new Firebase("https://.firebaseio.com");
  var authData = authref.getAuth();

  var ref = new Firebase("https://.firebaseio.com/quiz");
  ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      var record = data.val(); 
      if(record["name"] == name)
      {
         ref.remove(record.ref());
      }
    });
  });
```

I want to delete a quiz that belongs to the authenticated user and has the same name that is passed to the wrapper function.

I know that I need to pass the reference URL of the quiz, but I'm not sure how to get the ID because it's auto-generated by Firebase.

Below is an example of my data layout:

```
quiz
 -KDATEVU4fU5OF55fCbP
 -KDOIReUla7Fj1K62x7S
 -KDOJ-oI0JYmCdWrqrx_
 -KDPr7deQ5BHQcTwQ_cG
    name: "question"
    passcode: "9876"
    questions
      -KDPr82WcFw-jfuPz3T1
         0
          ans: "s"
          attempts: 0
          correct: 0
          qtext: "a"
          wrong1: "d"
          wrong2: "f"
          wrong3: "g"
          uid: "1f72bd29-967c-446d-a6b9-37ec9de540e0"
```

I'd be really grateful if anyone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just figured it out. I should have RTFM.

```
var authref = new Firebase("https://.firebaseio.com");
  var authData = authref.getAuth();

  var ref = new Firebase("https://.firebaseio.com/quiz");
  ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

      var record = data.val(); 

      if(record["name"] == name)
      {
        ref.child(data.key()).remove();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out on your own. It would be nice if you could also link to the FM that you should've RTd. :-)

Comment: What is "FM" and "RT"? Also, I think you can also use `data.ref.remove()`

Comment: Stands for "Read The F****** Manual" :)

Comment: @MosesAprico: calling `data.ref.remove()` will remove  the entire `quiz` node, not just the children that the query matches.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh whoop. Right.

Comment: ref.child(data.key).remove();

If you use the () operator on "key" you will find that it is not a function.