# Delete firebase query result

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

What I'm trying to accomplish is deleting a whole Firebase db query result entirely, without having to delete all records one by one.
I've read the documentation both on [deleting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) and [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) and [the most similar question on SO i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141627/firebase-delete-query-result) buth none of then was helpful.

This is my code on Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
const relatedElementsRef = databseRef.child('related_elements');

exports.onElementDeleted = functions.database
    .ref('elements/{user_id}/{element_id}')
    .onDelete(function (event) {
        var deletedElement = event.data.previous.val();

        const relatedElementsQuery = relatedElementsRef
            .child(event.params.user_id)
            .orderByChild('element_id')
            .equalTo(event.data.key)

        relatedElementsQuery.on("child_added", (relatedElementSnap, prevChildKey) => {
            relatedElementSnap.ref
                .remove()
                .then(()) => {
                    console.log("Related element deleted");
                });
        })
    });
```

What i would like to obtain is something similar to this:

```
//above code identical
        relatedElementsRef
            .child(event.params.user_id)
            .orderByChild('element_id')
            .equalTo(event.data.key)
            .remove()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Related elements deleted");
            });
//below code identical
```

Below a simplified structure of the database:

```
{
    "elements" : {
        "user_id" : {
          "element_id" : {
                "name" : "This is an element",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
    "related_elements": {
        "user_id" : {
          "related_element_id" : {
                "element_id" : "element_id", //Key of the object above
                "name" : "This is a related element",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. `equalTo`, et al. return `Query` instances and you cannot call `remove` on a query. You have to remove them one by one as in the answer you referenced.

Comment: @cartant Sadly you confirmed that it's a s i thought, I'll keep the current solution so. Thank you.